# Run maven with jvm args

Tags: java, maven, maven-surefire-plugin, jvm-arguments, mockk

I have a maven project where I want to run `mvn clean test` with `-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow` as an argument to the JVM. How do I do this? Is it correct to just write:
`mvn -Djvm.options=-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow clean test`

Edit:
The background for this is that mockk is failing with the following message:

```
  [ERROR]   Class cast exception happened.

WARN: 'message' property in ClassCastException provided by JVM is null, autohinting is not possible. 

This is most probably happening due to Java optimization enabled. 

You can use `hint` before call or use -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow to disable this optimization behaviour and make autohiniting work. 

For example in gradle use: 



test {

   jvmArgs '-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow'

}
```

I am running my tests with the maven-surefire-plugin and would like to pass this arg to the plugin.

Comment: Why do you need those parameters? Do you need them in your tests ?

Comment: @khmarbaise updated the question. Yes, I am using it for my tests.

Comment: As far as I remember it was something like -DXX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow but not sure.

Comment: Check also [MAVEN_OPTS](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#maven_opts-environment-variable).

Comment: I recommend to take a look into the documentation of maven-surefire-plugin/maven-failsafe-plugin where you can add args for the tests.

Comment: How is your surefire plugin configured? Depending on your setup, the tests do not necessarily run in the same JVM instance as your mvn process.